# single word for "true self"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Please is there a single word that describes the word "true self"?

I want to use it for a poetry line, e.g. in a phrase like "to  the fulfillment of my 'true self'."

Comment: "soul" is a word frequently used to describe one's essence

Comment: "Quiddity" is a sadly under-used word, but it's perhaps more ontological than poetic.

Comment: Some might prefer ' "Quiddity" is a sadly used word.'

Comment: Depending on the situation you might be able to use **identity**, **calling** or **essence** (mentioned by @Tom22).

Comment: Edwin's Comment is marvellous and even so, why would you want a single word for such a short and simple concept as *true self*, please?

Comment: my 'sum' may work

Answer (score 1):

*Nature* is the most poetic thing I can think of.

**Nature**. *Noun*.  The innate or essential qualities or character of a person or animal.

[Source (Google)](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+nature&oq=define+nature&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3321j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

other ideas: *core*, *being*, *essence*, *existence*, *spirit*, *soul* ?

Answer (score -1):

You might consider ***id***

Defined by [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/id) as:

> in psychoanalysis, the deepest part of the unconscious mind that represents the most basic natural human needs and emotions such as hunger, anger, and the wish for pleasure